# error: Cannot find OpenSceneGraph 3.2 or later

Tags: networking, software-installation

I am trying to setup omnet++ when I run `./configure` I endup with follwoing error:

```
.
.
.
configure: error: Cannot find OpenSceneGraph 3.2 or later - 3D view in Qtenv will not be available. Set WITH_OSG=no in configure.user to disable this feature or install the development package for OpenSceneGraph.
```

Running `osgversion` in same directory outputs:

```
OpenSceneGraph Library 3.6.4
```

I think that means OpenSceneGraph is installed fine, but I don't know what's causing this error and how to resolve it. Google only shows one result and that's from actual code on github where this error is written, no solution.

I did not change the configure.user file as mentioned in the error because I might need OpenSceneGraph for my work.
Link to installation guide for OMNeT++ is : [Installguide.pdf](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/InstallGuide.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

You have to install package with [development headers](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=openscenegraph.pc) by

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libopenscenegraph-dev
```

and then resume compilation.